# nested menu not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working nested menu item in angularjs. I want menu like this

- menu 1

  -submenu1

  -submenu2
- menu 2

  -submenu1

  -submenu2

```js
angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller("MainController", ["$scope", 
        function($scope){
          $scope.bodyText = "Test Menu";
          
          
           $scope.showSubmenu = function(item) {
            if($scope.activeParentIndex === item){
                $scope.activeParentIndex = "";
            }else{
                $scope.activeParentIndex = item;
            }
        }

        $scope.isShowing = function(index) {
            if($scope.activeParentIndex === index){
                return true;  
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        };
            
        $scope.modulos = 
          [
            {"module":"Admin System ",
           "adm_modulo_id":1,
           "submodule":[{"res":"Angular","url":"#/admin/1"},
                        {"res":"Linux","url":"#/admin/2"},
                        {"res":"Server","url":"#/admin/3"}
                        ]
            },
            {"module":"Admin System ",
           "adm_modulo_id":2,
           "submodule":[{"res":"Angular","url":"#/admin/1"},
                        {"res":"Linux","url":"#/admin/2"},
                        {"res":"Server","url":"#/admin/3"}
                        ]
            }

          ];

        }]);
```

Result :

- menu 1

  -submenu1

  -submenu2

  - menu 1

    -submenu1

    -submenu2
  - menu 2

    -submenu1

    -submenu2
  - menu 2

    -submenu1

    -submenu2

  But i am facing issue menu item are duplicated. please help me.

Comment: you can find full code in http://plnkr.co/edit/4qJv4iDdshJ5v2yIWJRX?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove duplicate `ng-repeat` from `sidebar-menu` from your `HTML` and change `m.submodule` to `item.submodule` in `sub-nav`

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
  <li class="treeview" ng-repeat="(itemIndex, item) in modulos">
    <a ng-click="showSubmenu(itemIndex)">
      <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>{{item.module}}</span>
    </a>

    <ul class="sub-nav" ng-show="isShowing(itemIndex)">
      <li ng-repeat="sub_element in item.submodule">
        <a href="{{sub_element.url}}">{{sub_element.res}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nUPx4SWQygpXc8yhjuad?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the `ng-repeat` on the ul. It seems like you wanted the li to repeat with its own sub-nav, not the ul (which was duplicating itself due to the 2 elements within `$scope.modulos`.

Also, Angular makes it easy to add properties to objects on the fly - I adjusted the `showSubmenu` method to just place a bool `showSubNav` to the module itself, toggling it every time the element is clicked.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cEqS727c3Hu0CObKCqV3?p=preview